# How to insert a byte array using prepared statement in node js to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi All I have a node program where I am trying to insert a byte array to database . My code  goes like this

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  (user_email,workbook_data) VALUES(?,?) ';
sql.query(query, [jsonData.userEmail, jsonData.workbook_data]);
```

Where jsonData.workbook_data is byte array
But I am getting below error when I execute the query

```
 code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',

  errno: 1136,

  sqlState: '21S01',

  sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",

  sql: "INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  (user_email,workbook_data) VALUES('name@company.com',80, 75, 3, 4)
```

For some reason instead of including passed array as [80,75,3,4] it is placing extracted data 80,75,3,4  in the query

What is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You are passing more data that columns exist.

```
(user_email,workbook_data) VALUES <------ Here are two columns of definition
('name@company.com',80, 75, 3, 4) <------ Here are four columns of data
```

Comment: Actualy I am not.   80,75,3,4 is part of the array . What I am  passing is ('name@company.com',[80, 75, 3, 4])  But when prepared statement executes it is turning into 80,75,3,4

Comment: so its 2 parameters. one is email, second is array of numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
const values = [jsonData.workbook_data]; // <-- fix

const query = 'INSERT INTO spreaddata.workbook  (user_email,workbook_data) VALUES(?,?) ';
sql.query(query, [jsonData.userEmail, values]); <-- fix
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.